# The syntax of the command is incorrect. at endlocal & set [batch]

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a function which returns value by reference in batch.

```
:errorCheck
setlocal
set "test_command=%~1"
set "err_code=%~2"
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('%test_command% 2^>^&1 1^>NUL') DO (
set err_msg="%%~a"
)
if [%err_msg%] neq [] (
    if not x%err_msg:%err_code%=%==x%err_msg% (
        set "error=true"
    )
)   

if [%err_msg%]==[] (
     set "error=false"
)
endlocal & set "%3=%error%"
exit /b
```

The function executes correctly and the return value is also correct but at line `endlocal & set "%3=%error%"` while executing `set "%3=%error%"` part it gives me error :

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

i am unable to comprehend why is it happening though the return value is correct.

Comment: What is the content of `%3`? You could try to run it with `ECHO ON` to see the expanded lines

Comment: How is the function being called?  In particular, are you passing it three parameters?  This is the error you would get by calling this code with only two parameters.

Comment: Btw. There are many errors in your code, like `x%err_msg:%err_code%=%` this will never replace anything

Comment: @jeb it is replacing, as it is supposed to. i have checked that with echo on.

Comment: @jeb ya i ran it with echo on, there what i see for endlocal & set "%3=%error%" is endlocal & set "%=true" or endlocal & set "%=false"

Comment: @jeb yes, function is called with three params , why will someone pass two params as all three of them are required.

Comment: Then your third parameter must be wrong, else `%3` would expand to something meaningfull, but you showed `set "%=false"` so your parameter must be something like `%%%%` so it expands to a single percent

Comment: i am sending third parameter as a boolean which is initially set to false. %3  will contain parameter 3 and i am setting that variable to decide later on the basis of return value. also when i used `%%%3%%` to replace that for actual variable it showed `%%%` on echo on

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the return value, but in the substring operation. Your syntax is not allowed. The expression is not evaluated as you think. The start and end of variables are

```
%err_msg:%err_code%=%
^........^        ^.^
var1              var2
```

To use a variable in a substring operation in another variable you will need to use delayed expansion. Try with

```dos
:errorCheck
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "test_command=%~1"
    set "err_code=%~2"
    set "error=false"
    set "err_msg="

    FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('
        %test_command% 2^>^&1 1^>NUL
    ') DO set "err_msg=%%~a"

    if defined err_msg (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if not "!err_msg:%err_code%=!"=="%err_msg%" (
            endlocal
            set "error=true"
        ) else ( endlocal )
    ) 

    endlocal & set "%3=%error%"
    exit /b
```

Now the variables seen by the parser are

```
!err_msg:%err_code%=!
         ^........^
^...................^
```

But as not all characters are allowed in a substrig operation, depending on the contents of `err_code` it is possible that it will also fail.

If it can be the case, you can change the substring operation into a piped command searching for the required error code

```dos
:errorCheck testCommand errorCode returnVariable
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    ( %~1 2>&1 1>nul | find "%~2" > nul ) && ( set "error=true" ) || ( set "error=false" )
    endlocal & set "%~3=%error%"
    exit /b
```

That is:

- execute the command (`%~1`) with, as in the original code, the stdout redirected to null and stderr redirected to stdout, so we read the error stream.
- The output of the command is filtered with `find`, searching the error code. If it is found, `find` will not raise error level, if it is not found, errorlevel will be raised.
- Using conditional execution, the `error` variable is set. If the previous command does not raise errorlevel, the code after the `&&` is executed. If the command raised errorlevel, the code after the `||` is executed.
- Environment space is restored and the return variable asigned

Comment: well the programming what is intended to do but i see ur point. 
can you please explain how will it work `( %~1 2>&1 1>nul | find "%~2" > nul ) && ( set "error=true" ) || ( set "error=false" )`

Comment: @SubhamTripathi, answer updated with detailed description. Sorry for not doing it before.

Comment: sorry but the question i have posted is working fine without any changes. or the changes i am not aware of , as it was under continuous development but i haven't changed any thing. so ur solutions doesnt work for me, i am sorry. though the explanation have provided me some new insights.